# OSX/Unix process-specific link

Tags: macos, unix, command-line-interface

I would like to be able to run a process where it "recognizes" a symbolic link that isn't really there. (Not really a link, but something where all read/writes to a directory are redirected to another directory for one specific process run from the command line)

For example, run safari (/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari) with a link from ~/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins to ~/Desktop/SafariPlugins, so it loads plugins from ~/Desktop/SafariPlugins instead of the first path, but all other programs (Firefox...) would still be able to access ~/Library/Internet\ Plug-ins/ and wouldn't recognize the symbolic link.

I would like to also implement this in several other instances, so it needs to be not specific to web browsers and plugins.

I would expect this to happen through the command line, and I have superuser access if that is necessary, but I see no reason for it to be.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that superuser access won't help, but that's because I don't think what you're after is doable.  At the least, POSIX doesn't define such a mechanism.  That means you're into o/s or file system specific features.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As root on a Linux box I could do it just fine, but I don't think OSX has the necessary API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there, done that, found out what a headache it is.

Basically what you're going to write is a system call wrapper for open() that if given one path converts it to the other.

I submit this problem is inherently hard. `LD_PRELOAD` is your friend to get your wrapper loaded. Normally in such a wrapper I directly invoke system calls but you may have a hard time of it (gcc will inline them sometimes--which may also be your undoing).

The process of writing this thing is inherently like writing a libc based rootkit. I refer you to this concept specifically because it is well-documented and the technique otherwise is poorly documented. Otherwise it is known to me only in Valgrind and demonstration examples. You must cover all system calls that manipulate file names that the application is going to use, including open(), creat(), rename(), unlink(), link(), symlink(), and stat(). If your platform does not apply LD_PRELOAD overrides when loading libc, you must also tap fopen(), opendir(), rename(), and a few others. This gets painful fast.

Comment: that is as close as I'm going to get. Thanks and I found a site https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/ and I think I can get the rest. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can this work if the executable is not written in c? Say swift or obj-c...?

Comment: @Gregory_Ling: Yes. You certainly have to write your intercept library in C but the language of the main executable should not matter.

Comment: So I only need to wrap the open() call? or do I have to wrap fopen, open, and every other file open I can find? I tried just fopen and it didn't work for TextEdit for example. Sorry I am clueless...

Comment: @Gregory_Ling: You need to wrap open(), and possibly a few more depending on how Safari opens directories. If you're clueless enough to not be able to debug this mistake you're going to have a hard time at it and I regret giving you the right answer and should have told you it was impossible.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for your help anyway. I think I know enough to figure it out. I just wasn't sure if I had to wrap every function and how much effort it would take because if it takes that much effort, I might just not do it. Thanks. Your answer was correct because there is a way, even if it is hard to do.